# Вероятность победы команды

Tags: python

Сидел я и придумывал задачку на python. Суть следующая.
Команда 1 забивает в 3 случаях из 7 например.
Команда 2 забивает в 2 случаях из 6 например.
Как просчитать вероятность победы одной из команд, если количество атак каждой команды - 10.

Возможно элементарный вопрос, но буду рад за помощь) Спасибо)

Comment: Задача - чистый тервер. И никаким боком к питону. Или на нём надо помонтекарлить?

Answer (score 1):

Тервер в помощь - 
http://www.matburo.ru/tv_spr_sub.php?p=1

а так, просто исходя из здравого смысла:
3/7 = 0.44
2/6 = 0.33
из чего вне зависимости от количества атак
вероятность победы команды 1 - 44%
вероятность победы команды 2 - 33%

Comment: ага. ну да. а если одна команда забивает в 6 из 7 случаев, а вторая 5 из 7 случаев, то вероятности: 86 и 71%. ага. так и будет. за формулы спасибо - я и сам нашел.

Comment: Вероятность не считается в процентах. Вас кто то жестоко обманул.